# Help identify this seedling (baobab?)

Tags: identification, seeds, germination, seedlings, urban-gardening

Can anyone identify this seedling?

I bought (what I thought were) baobab seeds online. When they arrived they looked nothing like I expected, small and brown and glossy, resembling apple seeds (see picture).

One of the 10 seeds germinated and is growing well - I’m not sure it’s a baobab though! 2 thick starter leaves and some fern-like fronds which open in the day and close at night. Seems like a very cool plant!!

Any one have any idea?

Cheers

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [tamarind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamarind) seed. The Tamarindus indica has a pinnate leaf as in your seedling, has distinctively shiny seeds and the leaves close at night. Mind you, there are many other tropical leaves that close at night as well, largely in the Mimosa family (also a pea type plant) but they have different seeds.

Unfortunately it is not a baobab. Baobab seeds are distinctly dull and bulky with a curvy shape. The leaves are not pinnate, but palmate, that is 5 leaflets arranged radially on a leaf stalk.

Answer (score 2):

I do belive this is an open pollinated *Jacaranda mimosafolia*.[image: 3 Jacaranda Mimosafolia seedlings as they "fall asleep" for the night and a hand full of seeds they came from][image]

Comment: Nice answer (if want to italicise a scientific name, can type a single underscore character immediately before the text, and then also type a single underscore character immediately after the text)

Comment: @MH or you could just _show_ our new user how it’s done ;-) BTW, asterisks (*) will also work. Welcome, Davis!